# tOra says there's no connection provider

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, connection, qt4, tora

I installed tOra (pl/SQL editor) on ubuntu 12.04, after opening the software says: there's no connection provider

I need to connect it to a postgres database.

Any idea?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

MySQL, PostgreSQL, Microsoft SQL, ODBC providers:

```
sudo apt-get install libqt4-sql-mysql libqt4-sql-psql libqt4-sql-sqlite libqt4-sql-odbc libqt4-sql-tds
```

Comment: I want to use oracle provider? what shoud I install ?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure because I use all of them

Answer (score 8):

After installing `libqt4-sql-psql` (qt4 postgres adapter) the problem was solved.

```
apt-get install libqt4-sql-psql
```